# Json parsing gives error when using special characters in the data

Tags: javascript, php

I am facing a json parsing error. I send a get request to my server and server returns a json data. The request is sent from a wordpress site. So the json data is then encoded by php function. It works with normal texts but it doesn't work when special characters are in the data.

Here are my data returned from my server. I am trying to parse the data using `JSON.parse(myData)`

```js
console.log(JSON.parse({"Sun Jun 21 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (+06)":[{"id":17,"club_id":8,"isPublished":1,"eventName":"Ölprovning","eventImg":"/uploads/zHvJJJk6bG8eqjKcWpNRBevha6ZlyMTYGqC9k6Oe.jpeg","eventLocation":"TVÅ FETA GRISAR | Hisingen","eventDate":"2020-06-20T18:00:00.000Z","eventTime":"08:00","eventFee":300,"eventLimit":49,"eventDescription":"Var med på vår ölprovning av våra nya öl 2020. Vi har 8 st helt nya öl för säsongen, vilken är din favorit?
Vi öppnar portarna kl 19:30 för de som är registrerade som vipkund","publish":"","recurringDays":0,"created_at":"2020-06-15 15:43:47","updated_at":"2020-06-15 15:43:47","accepted":[],"__meta__":{"singedup_count":0},"dayName":"Sun","monthName":"June","dayOfTheMonth":"21"}],"Wed Jul 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (+06)":[{"id":16,"club_id":8,"isPublished":1,"eventName":"Padelresa","eventImg":"/uploads/LYtDyBC65IhXZhaQeKko2UjzViGxkYnFTKVYLXVF.jpeg","eventLocation":"Marbella","eventDate":"2020-07-28T18:00:00.000Z","eventTime":"08:00","eventFee":8900,"eventLimit":20,"eventDescription":"Häng med till häftiga Marbella ocean club och lira padel 10 gånger under 5 dAGAR
BOKA DIN RESA SENAST 12 JULI","publish":"Web","recurringDays":0,"created_at":"2020-05-15 22:58:07","updated_at":"2020-06-15 16:23:53","accepted":[],"__meta__":{"singedup_count":0},"dayName":"Wed","monthName":"July","dayOfTheMonth":"29"}],"Tue Aug 25 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (+06)":[{"id":18,"club_id":8,"isPublished":1,"eventName":"Golfresa","eventImg":"/uploads/GpY06zAiBXwLaQntDVcmSDAhaC3K7G4UiJy3cVKA.jpeg","eventLocation":"Florida | West palm Beach Golf resort","eventDate":"2020-08-24T18:00:00.000Z","eventTime":"02:00","eventFee":9,"eventLimit":49,"eventDescription":"Meloneras GC är förmodligen den dyraste golfbana som byggts i florida  och då beror det varken på att klubbhuset är enormt, för det är ganska litet och oansenligt, eller på att man behövt spränga bort stora berg, utan det är marken – läget.

Golfbanan går längs havet där man annars bara bygger hotell och lyxvillor på Gran Canaria. Banan är skönt komponerad och växer ju mer man spelar. Öppningen är lite försiktig och man lär successivt känna karaktären och hastigheten på greenerna. En av många utmaningar kommer på det femte hålet, ett kort par 3-hål. Det är lätt att bli lurad här och tro att detta är en enkel match, men det gäller att hålla tungan rätt i mun för annars finns risken att du slår i vattnet. Det känns skönt att kunna använda alla klubborna i bagen och på de första 9 hålen kan man sprida bollarna ganska friskt utan att bestraffas alltför hårt. Även om de första 9 hålen är väldigt bra så har man från klubbhuset sett vad som väntar – och det är de sista 9 hålen som ofta blir avgörande för scoren. Inte alla av de sista 9 hålen går vid havet, men havet är så dominerande att man ändå får den känslan. De sista nio hålens verkliga signaturhål är 12:an som är ett tufft par 3-hål. Här får man den magiska känslan av att nästan slå rakt ut mot havet. Greenen ligger verkligen på kanten mot Atlanten. Till Meloneras vill man komma tillbaka och det märks tydligt på alla våra gäster som väljer att komma hit år efter år.
7 nätter i dubbelrum
7 frukostar och 6 middagar
5 heldagsgreenfee
flyg
flygskatt
transport av golfbag
flygplatstransfer
service av vår golfvärd och pro","publish":"","recurringDays":0,"created_at":"2020-06-15 15:50:14","updated_at":"2020-06-15 15:51:55","accepted":[],"__meta__":{"singedup_count":0},"dayName":"Tue","monthName":"August","dayOfTheMonth":"25"}]}))
```

Comment: The only special characters that matter are line breaks, and your JSON looks invalid for that reason.

Comment: ok so line break is the problem here?

Comment: Strings cannot include line breaks.

Comment: Thanks got it. Yes removing lines works. you can post it as an answer. Is there any work around with the line break?

Comment: Well the work-around is to make sure your JSON-encoding library does not put newlines in the middle of string values.

Comment: `JSON.parse({"Sun Jun`? This is not JSON, it isn't even a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON syntax does not allow "raw" newlines in the middle of string values. You can use `\n` to include a newline (well, technically a linefeed) character. Generally, the correct thing to do is to use a proven JSON-encoding library to transform a server-side data structure into compliant JSON notation.

Comment: In fact this question is the classical confusion between JSON and JavaScript. Certainly neither JSON nor JavaScript double-quoted string literals allow line feeds but there's much more wrong in the original code because `JSON.parse()` expects a string, not an arbitrary data structure.